# iTunesU Note-taking API or File Backup?

Tags: ios, api, backup, file-format

The [new iTunesU iPhone app](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/07/25/apple-updates-itunes-u-with-note-taking-and-improved-search/) has been updated with note-taking and searching ability. One thing I'm curious about, is where and in what format are notes stored? Is there an API to edit or backup notes and their relation to content, or access notes from another program?

Comment: My guess it'd be CoreData backend with Spotlight search abilities (like in OS X, but private).

Answer (score 0):

I believe iTunes U stores it's notes through iCloud (hence the sync option). And there are no API's to access any iTunes U information at this time.

Comment: If it's iCloud, wouldn't there be an API? Perhaps somewhere in this documentation? https://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php

Comment: No, because when you use iClouds API's, everything you do is unique to that specific application. Meaning it's like having a local variable that not just anyone can access unless your inside the application.

Comment: So no one can access the data? Even with Jailbreak?

Comment: @NoBugs Maybe with a Jailbreak, but I doubt on exists let alone with the documentation necessary to access those API's. IF you really want to access that information, you'd have to do a lot of detective work and figure out A. where the info is, and B. how to change it to your needs.